# Password Encryption Mechanism over HTTP Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

My App has Login Form. And its about Money transfer. I use Web service to Send and Receive Username and Password. what kind of Encryption Mechanism i should use. How should i Use it. My code is Like the Below

> ```
>  email=emailTextField.text;
>  //[email encodeWithCoder:]
>  password=passwordTextfield.text;
>
> NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:MY URL Email=%@&Password=%@",email,password]];
>
> NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
> [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
>
> NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"administrator", @"password"];
>
> NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
> NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
>
> NSLog(@"%@",authValue);//
> [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
> [request setURL:url2];
>
> NSLog(@"%@",url2);
>
> NSError *error;
>
> NSURLResponse *response;
>
> NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
>
> NSLog(@"Data is %@",data);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form is like an html form you don't need encryption You must have a SSL connection (https://) after that it will be transferred on secured connection.

Comment: but we are not using SSL connection as of now.

Comment: hmm that is not good idea at all. then use hash salt Mechanism and keep your key secret

Answer (score 0):

I would use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) to do AES Encryption for pwd and send it with session_token

data = ENCRYPTED_PWD|TOKEN